# How can I save files to my Project folder c#

Tags: c#, file-writing

Thank you all I have found a viable solution with the aid of @NigelWhatling.

I want to store the file within the project folder and not inside the debug folder where it is currently saving to.

So I have used direct locations to save my files howerver I want to save them within the project folder. I have tried to use the code :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

code example :

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string NameOfFile = "test.txt";
string path= Path.Combine(directory , NameOfFile );

using (StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {

                sw.WriteLine("Hello world");
            }
```

This code gives me the location of where the programme was run

```
C:\Users\sam\source\repos\Project\server\bin\Debug
```

But I want to save within the Project folder where all the projects file are located. How can I do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where is it saving to and where do you want it to save to specifically, also can you provide any code in regards to what youre attempting to do?

Comment: You mean you want to save them where the source code is located? Why?

Comment: I have gotten it working with the direct path however I want to store them within the project folder so i can run the application on  another computer.

Comment: @ It is saving within the server debug folder where the server programme is located. I would like to save the file within the Project Folder which holds both server and client folders.

Comment: @mason I want to store it there so that if I were to copy the project folder the application will save and load files correctly if I were to run the application from another computer.

Comment: The executable itself has no concept of the build environment that created it (unless you specifically provide that information to it). You won't be able to automatically determine where the base path of your project is. If you have a set scenario (e.g. exe is always under server\bin\Debug), just manipulate (trim) the path that you get back from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.

Comment: @NigelWhatling how could I try the path so I get only the Project folder

Comment: you should save and load files in a well defined place, like the users app_data, ProgramData, a subdir of where the binary is. Storing in the proj dir makes no sense at all. UNless this is a tool that writes source code, some kind of templating engine you are building

Comment: @pm100 I am trying to get it to save within the Project folder so that I can then copy the Project folder and run it on a new machine. At the moment if I were to run the application on a new machine the files will not be loaded as the path is not valid.

Comment: place the files in the source directory,add them to the project, mark them as 'always copy' VS will copy them to the bin directory for  you. In your code use executingassembly.location to find the files

Answer (score 1):

You can include any kind of file in your project. If you are using Visual Studio, you can drag-n-drop them to the project in VS's Solution Explorer, or right-click the project and choose 'Add' -> 'Existing item...'.